# iPhone development - UIWebview : Failing while using the method :loadHTMLString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to receive the UIWebView event 'didFailLoadWithError' when trying to load an html document with the web view's method 'loadHTMLString()'? 
I tried several ways but the web view always loads successfully.
Should I even implement the 'didFailLoadWithError' event if I am only using the 'loadHTMLString()' method?

Comment: Have you checked if webViewDidFinishLoad method is called or not? By saying that i mean whether you have set the delegate properly or not?

Comment: It is called. I am asking a diffrent question. I want to know if an error could occur if I am using the 'loadHTMLString()' method. meaning, should I implement the 'didFailLoadWithError' event? And if so, could someone give me a scenario that could cause this? ('didFailLoadWithError' is called instead of 'webViewDidFinishLoad' when calling the web view's 'loadHTMLString()' method )

Comment: can you add some code, what all method you have used for web view, so that it's easy to figure out the exact problem?